# Random variable with Bernoulli variable

Tags: variance, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

Say $X$ is a variable with $P(X=1)=p$ and $P(X=0)=1-p$. Find $E(Y)$ and $\text{var}(Y)$ for each of the following:

(a) $Y=2X$

(b) $Y=X^2$

(c) $Y=2^X$

---

Okay, so I'm thinking that:

(a) $E(Y) = 2p$ and $\text{var}(Y)=2p(1-p)$

(b) $E(Y) = p$ and $\text{var}(Y)=p(1-p)$

(c) $E(Y) = 2^p$ and $\text{var}(Y) = 2^{p(1-p)}$

But I also could be way off. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In (a) we have var(Y)= 4 Var(X) not 2 Var(X).  In (b) E(X)=p and E(Y)=p and Var(Y)=E(X$^2$-p)$*2=(1-p)$^2.  In (c) E(Y) =p (2$^1$) +(1-p) (2$^0$)=1+p. and Var(Y)=E(2$^X$-(1+p))$^2$. You should be able to calculate this.

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Comment: In (b) I meant Var(Y)=E(X$^2$-p)$^2$= p(1-p)$^2$ +(1-p)(0-p)$^2$=p(1-2p+p$^2$)+p$^2$=p-p$^2$+p$^3$

Comment: With respect to a), if $\sigma^2(x) = 2$, what does $\sigma^2(2x)$ equal?  Work it out with a simple example if you don't know the answer.  With respect to c), you're wrong.  Note that $2^x \in \{1,2\}$ and work through the algebra, don't just try to mimic a pattern in one formula and apply it to another - that very, very rarely works.